# Sort by specific object property value (number, string) optimization

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pinia

I want to simplify a method of sorting number and string values, where first, I check if my passed parameter (which is of type DeliveryDetailsColumns contants) is the same string as the one parameter of another type (EletronicDeliveryType)

```
export const DeliveryDetailsColumns = {
  Title: "title",
  ExpectedDelivery: "expectedDelivery",
  Price: "price",
  Quantity: "quantity",
};

export interface ElectronicDeliveryType {
  title?: string;
  quantity?: number;
  price?: number;
  expectedDelivery?: string;
}
```

I have the array of objects in pinia of name filteredValues, type of ElectronicDeliveryType.
I want to sort selected column, for now I have not so generic method where I do a switch case through all of the DeliveryDetailsColumns options and I would like to make it generic with the names of ElectronicDeliveryType - DeliveryDetailsColumns check and check of the types of property, what can be the solution here?

```
 sortBySelectedColumnOrder(columnName: string, sortOrder: string) {
      if (sortOrder === "ascending") {
        switch (columnName) {
          case DeliveryDetailsColumns.Title:
            this.filteredValues.sort((a, b) =>
              a!.title!.toLowerCase() > b!.title!.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1
            );
            break;
          case DeliveryDetailsColumns.Price:
            this.filteredValues.sort((a, b) => a!.price! - b!.price!);
            break;
            [...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a map of delivery details to their respective comparator function:

```js
const comparators = new Map<
    keyof typeof DeliveryDetailsColumns,
    (a: ElectronicDeliveryType, b: ElectronicDeliveryType) => number
>([
    [DeliveryDetailsColumns.Title, (a, b) => a!.title!.toLowerCase() > b!.title!.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1],   
    [DeliveryDetailsColumns.Price, (a, b) => a!.price! - b!.price!)],
]);
```

Then you can just do a lookup on the map:

```js
this.filteredValues.sort(comparators.get(columnName)!);
```

But make sure to check if the column exists first:

```js
if (!comparators.has(columnName)) { ... }
```